# Odoo create stock.move.line

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

when i try to create stock move line in transfer with automation with the following code, error pop up saying "psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block".

The code:

```
result=[]

result.append(
  {'company_id':record.partner_id.id,
  'date':record.date,
  'location_dest_id':5,
  'location_id':8 ,
  'product_uom_qty':1,
  'product_uom_id':32,
  'product_id':465
  })

env['stock.move.line'].create(result)
```

May I ask any idea what is the problem with my code or how can i programmtically create stock move line. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting the whole object into `create()` instead of wrapping it inside an array?

Comment: just tried,  same result

Answer (score 0):

You set the `company_id` to the `partner_id` which may not be present in `res.company` table and
if it happens you should see the following error message:

```
DETAIL:  Key (company_id)=(...) is not present in table "res_company".
```

This will prevent Odoo from creating a stock move line, try to set the `company_id` to `self.env.user.company_id.id`

Note that since v12 Odoo supports passing a list of values to [create](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/models.py#L3512) function